# GraphQL (Apollo), Sequelize, MySQL & using non-standard foreign keys

Tags: graphql, sequelize.js, apollo-server

I am working on a GraphQL server with Apollo, Sequelize, Node and MySQL. The data consists of videos and teams (in those videos). I am also using non-standard foreign keys to connect teams to a specific video (database table Teams has a field called 'inVideo' instead of the default 'VideoId' one). Creating videos and teams as well as querying specific ones (with id) or all items is not a problem. However, when I am trying to query teams belonging to a specific video (by providing the id of the specific video) the SQL SELECT query on the backend contains an additional field name, which is the default foreign key construct 'VideoId", and as that field does not exist on the database, the query fails.

Here is the migration file to create the Teams table (note the inVideo-field definition):

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Teams', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      inVideo: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Teams');
  }
};
```

Here is the team model definition for Sequelize (note the foreignKey definition in belongsTo)

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Team extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Team.belongsTo(models.Video, { foreignKey: "inVideo" })
    }
  }
  Team.init({
    name: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Team',
  });
  return Team;
};
```

There is nothing special in the migration file for generating video table in the database, but here is the Sequelize model file for video (as I added the hasMany relationship in that model):

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Video extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Video.hasMany(models.Team)
    }
  }
  Video.init({
    videoUrl: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Video',
  });
  return Video;
};
```

Then the GraphQL schema definition

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server');
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Video {
    id: Int!
    videoUrl: String!
    teams: [Team!]!
  }

  type Team {
    id: Int!
    name: String!
    video: Video!
  }

  type Query {
    teams(inVideo: Int!): [Team!]!
  }

  type Mutation {
    createVideo(videoUrl: String!): Video!
    createTeam(inVideo: Int!, name: String!): Team!
  }
`;
module.exports = typeDefs;
```

And finally the resolver definitions for the server:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    async teams(root, { inVideo }, { models }) {
      return models.Team.findAll({
        where: {
          inVideo: inVideo
        }
      });
    },
  },
  Mutation: {
    async createVideo(root, { videoUrl }, { models }) {
      return models.Video.create({ videoUrl });
    },
    async createTeam( root, { inVideo, name }, { models }) {
      return models.Team.create({ inVideo, name });
    },
  },
  Video: {
    async teams(video) {
      return video.getTeams();
    },
  },
  Team: {
    async video(team) {
      return team.getVideo();
    },
  },  
};
module.exports = resolvers;
```

As noted, creating the videos and teams works ok, and the data in the database is correct. However when I try to query the server to get the teams for a certain video, the SQL SELECT clause is as follows:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `inVideo`, `VideoId` FROM `Teams` AS `Team` WHERE `Team`.`inVideo` = 1;
```

The VideoId field should not be in there, as it does not exist in the database (the relation information is stored in the field inVideo).

How can I get rid of this behavior? (I thought that the foreignKey option in the belongsTo method call takes care of this)

Also, my way of defining the relation / querying teams using the relation (using where-option for findAll) might be incorrect. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use your own explicit foreign key field don't forget to indicate it for associations on both ends:

```js
Video.hasMany(models.Team, { foreignKey: "inVideo" })
```

Otherwise, Sequelize will use the default foreign key name `ModelName+Id` (`VideoId` in this case).

Comment: Arghhh... but of course! Thank you! It works!